# Call constructor on double array via Streams

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if the following is possible with Java 8, for:

```
Patch[][] patches = new Patch[width][depth];
```

I want to call the constructor using `Stream`s, I know there is `Arrays.stream(patches)` which would give me a `Stream<Patch[]>`, so unfortunately I do not think that is of any use (yet in my idea).

In old Java this would come down to the simple:

```
for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++) {
        patches[w][z] = new Patch();
    }
}
```

The most useful method would be one that destructs a `T[][]` to a `Stream<T>` I think.

To rephrase what I actually want: Convert the double `for`-loop to a statement using Java 8, most likely involving `Stream`.

Comment: What's your question exactly? First you tell you want to call a constructor using Streams (what does that mean?). Then you're talking about Arrays.stream(), which makes a stream out of an array, and then you show a nested loop which populates an array. I can't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet Edited the question, I'm simply looking for a simpler way to write code.

Comment: You are trying to achieve a pure side-effect of populating an existing array. Streams are not about that because you are not doing any *processing of items in the stream*.

Comment: I *was* pretty sure that there was a way to call the constructor on all elements of a Stream, however now I am not so sure if that is even possible.

Comment: What you *are* doing (in a way) is processing nested streams of `int` indices. So perhaps make an `intStream` or similar, and use `forEach` to do `patches[w][z] = new Patch()`. Not that you'll gain much---as I said, streams are not about this kind of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working, after some learning of how lambda's work:

```
Arrays.stream(patches)
        .forEach(pArray -> Arrays.parallelSetAll(pArray, i -> new Patch()));
```

First I'll explain a simpler version:

```
Object[] test = new Object[10];
Arrays.parallelSetAll(test, i -> new Object());
```

What the last version does is first allocate a `Object[10]`, an array of ten `Object`s. Then it uses one of the new `Arrays.parallelSetAll` methods which has the following signature:

```
public static <T> void parallelSetAll(T[] array,
                                      IntFunction<? extends T> generator)
```

And in this case I have used for `IntFunction<? extends T> generator` a lambda expression: `i -> new Patch()`, which generates a `new Patch()`, for every `i`: In this case we do not need the `i` though, but we *do* need it to construct a correct lambda expression.

Also note that `Object::new` cannot be used (*as far as I know*), it then gives the message:

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      Object is not a functional interface)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>parallelSetAll(T[],IntFunction<? extends T>)
```

To come back on the actual answer on my question: What I do there is pretty similar to what I have just explained, except that I have a `Patch[][]` as input, and I first need to loop over that, which I accomplish via:

`Arrays.stream(patches).forEach()`, which has as signature: `void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`.

Here I then use the lambda expression `pArray -> Arrays.parallelSetAll(pArray, i -> new Patch())`.

So effectively this first loops over all `Patch[]` arrays, and then parallel sets all elements of `Patch[]` to be `new Patch()`.

Whether or not it is actually easier than a double for-loop is debatable, but I can argue that the amount of code is atleast the same and possibly easier to type due to no need for enters, extra curly braces, etc.

This maybe also can be written even easier, so comments on that are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm at work and can't install it to actually test this, but if you really want to use Java 8 to fill your 2d array with new `Patch` instances you can do it like this:

```
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class PatchArrayGenerator implements IntFunction<Patch[]>
{
    private final int depth;

    public PatchArrayGenerator(int depth)
    {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public Patch[] apply(int value)
    {
        Patch[] patchArray = new Patch[depth];
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(patchArray, value -> new Patch());
        return patchArray;
    }
}

public class PatchMaker
{     
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int depth = 5, width = 5;
        Patch[][] patches = new Patch[width][depth];
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(patches, new PatchArrayGenerator(depth));
    }
}
```

If you're bored you can refactor the `PatchArrayGenerator` class to create any type you want instead of just Patches.

I would definitely stick to the nested loop though :)

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it inspired my own answer, what I'd recommend you though is to rely more on actual lambda expressions, instead of implementing the actual functional interfaces.